# 4x3 Layout in Tipboard results in 500 Internal Server Error. Is this the result of Tipboard code?

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, dashboard

I'm trying to set the layout of my [tipboard](http://allegro.tech/tipboard/) dashboard to be 4 columns and three rows, by editing the YAML code in `~\.tipboard\layout_config.yaml`, as per the [configuration documentation](https://tipboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html). However, changing the layout from 4x2 to 4x3 (by duplicating the last row's configuration) results in a `500 Internal Server Error` message. Restarting the tipboard server makes no difference.

I have checked that the YAML uses spaces and not tabs. I have also validated it with [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/).

In case it's relevant: I'm running this on 64bit Windows 10 and haven't tested on GNU/Linux.

Does tipboard not support this layout or do I need to edit/override its code? If so, how?

4x2 YAML:

```
details:
    page_title: Empty Dashboard
layout:
    - row_1_of_2:
        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_2_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_3_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_4_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

    - row_2_of_2:
        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_2_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_3_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_4_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:
```

To produce the 4x3 layout, duplicate the section for `row_2_of_2` and rename rows appropriately (`row_1_of_3`, `row_2_of_3` and `row_3_of_3`). The result is as below:

```
details:
    page_title: Empty Dashboard
layout:
    - row_1_of_3:
        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

    - row_2_of_3:
        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

    - row_3_of_3:
        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:

        - col_1_of_4:
            - tile_template: empty
              tile_id: empty
              title: Empty Tile
              classes:
```

The console output from tipboard is as follows:

```
$ tipboard runserver
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
[I 170807 10:33:54 console:145] Following keys already in Redis:

[I 170807 10:33:54 console:160] Listening on port localhost:7272...
[E 170807 10:34:02 web:1121] Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
    HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:7272', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', body='', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Host': 'localhost:7272', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1077, in _execute
        *self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tipboard\app.py", line 250, in get
        page_title=flipboard.get_flipboard_title(),
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tipboard\app.py", line 53, in get_flipboard_title
        config = process_layout_config(config_names[0])
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tipboard\parser.py", line 116, in process_layout_config
        config['tiles_names'], config['tiles_keys'] = _find_tiles_names(layout)
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tipboard\parser.py", line 59, in _find_tiles_names
        for row in _get_rows(layout):
      File "c:\usr\local\virtualenv\tipboard\lib\site-packages\tipboard\parser.py", line 53, in _get_rows
        raise WrongSumOfRows('The sum of the lines is incorrect.')
    WrongSumOfRows: The sum of the lines is incorrect.
[E 170807 10:34:02 web:1514] 500 GET / (::1) 82.00ms
[W 170807 10:34:02 web:1514] 404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 4.00ms
```

Comment: That is correct YAML, but without the actual 4x3 layout it is difficult to tell if that is correct as well. Might be that your (Windows) editor thinks it can insert tabs instead of spaces, which would cause havoc.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks. I've checked the tabs vs spaces issue and updated the question with complete YAML for the 4x3 layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusing thing about the configuration file is that it specifies the **dimension** of the item (row, column or panel), not the **position** of the item. Therefore, rather than specify the number of the row (1, 2 or 3), specify its height (1 row high, in a configuration of 3 rows).

**Wrong:** `row_1_of_3`, `row_2_of_3`, `row_3_of_3` (position: 1 row high within 3, 2 rows high within 3, 3 rows high within 3 = 6 rows within 3)

**Right:** `row_1_of_3`, `row_1_of_3`, `row_1_of_3` (height: 3 rows, each 1 row high = 3 rows within 3)

Repeat the below thrice, **without changing** the height of the row (once for each row of 3 rows):

```
- row_1_of_3:
    - col_1_of_4:
        - tile_template: empty
          tile_id: empty
          title: Empty Tile
          classes:

    - col_1_of_4:
        - tile_template: empty
          tile_id: empty
          title: Empty Tile
          classes:

    - col_1_of_4:
        - tile_template: empty
          tile_id: empty
          title: Empty Tile
          classes:

    - col_1_of_4:
        - tile_template: empty
          tile_id: empty
          title: Empty Tile
          classes:
```